# Win 10 computer does not recognize ESP8266, no blue LED

Tags: arduino-esp8266

Flashed five ESP8266 ESP-12e by using NodeMCU firmware. Then inserted each into the USB and no blue LED on the board came on. Only flashes momentarily when inserted then turns off. After this the "device manager" said we did have a COM9 port. Now COM9 is not there in the device manager. I have the drivers for CH341SER and CP2102 installed.

Arduino IDE has "port" but grayed out.
ESPlorer says "could not find any serial port".
NodeMCU says "Error:Serial port not exist".

Any possible solutions or should I throw the computer into a river?

Comment: Throwing computer into river is never a good solution.

Comment: Migrate to linux.?

Comment: By ESP8266 e12 I assume you meant ESP-12e module? Since it has no USB to UART chip, the problem should be with your USB to UART adapter and not the module itself. Does the port show up with only adapter connected without the module? Could be a problem with power supply.

Comment: Did not use USB to UART adapter when flashed the five ESP8266 E12 (12E?).  I have one ESP8266 12E not flashed with others.  When plugged into win10 computer the blue light remains lighted on this one BUT windows does not recognize it, ie no beep beep.  Go to device manager and click on "SHOW HIDDEN DEVICES" results in 9 com ports being displayed  including "Silicon Labe CP210x USB to UART Bridge (COM8).

Comment: Thank you for your assistance and I do appreciate your concern.  I just re-read my initial question.  I apologize for not being specific about exact problem.  Too many words.  Win 10 did let me program all my ESP 12E  modules.  Then it would not recognize any of them.  That is it, the problem.  I can now plug them into USB ports and Win 10 ignores the modules.  I can not program them because I cannot access them.  I ordered two more and Win 10 ignores them also.  Nearest river is very far away but it is tempting me.

Answer (score 2):

Some laptops couldn't provide enough power to USB ports generating erratic behavior when connecting, Wifi connections draws much more power than a typical Arduino board. Try to use an externally powered USB dock. Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. Successfully flashed the hardware with a custom .bin file made online through https://nodemcu-build.com/ then followed this tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-oSjMCmNYk now I can upload custom programs in c language to the node mcu hardware.

You will have to then restart your arduino IDE or whatever system/software you're using and follow the basic requirements to download the board related software and options in the ide there's plenty of tutorials for that basic work. The most important is the first step above.

Let me know if that worked for you or if you need further assistance.

Cheers

Comment: Elation reigns supreme.   Trying to make win 10 recognize esp8266 12E with no success for several - many - weeks now with no success.  Then yesterday win 10 did recognize an esp8266.   Not only that but another afflicted similarly computer in the same room did likewise.  Really weird because I did nothing for several days in re to situation???  Now can download sketch with either computer.   Thanks for assistance.

Comment: Bad news.   It has reverted to it's not recognizing anyof my esp8266s.   Oh fudge.

Comment: @jfolse, I have the same problem. Did you solve it? If so, could you share the solution?

Answer (score -2):

It looks like bad USB cable. Try another one.